# Interpreting JVM method call instructions

Tags: java, jvm, instructions

I understand that the instruction below means a method call has taken place:

```
invokestatic:indexbyte1=00 indexbyte2=02
```

My understanding is that to find the index in the Constant Pool of the method being called, the bit shift operation is performed:

```
00 << 8 + 02
```

This equals to zero, which is not a valid entry in the Constant Pool index. Am I misunderstanding the calculation required?

I would like to understand how this is done manually, so a decompiler will not help.

Comment: if you would like to calculate it in java you should use: 0x00 << 8 + 0x02

Comment: OP is not asking about Java (the language), but rather about the instructions executed by the JVM, i.e., the output of javac.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The index is not calculated as `00 << 8 + 02`. To quote [the standard](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.invokestatic):

> The unsigned indexbyte1 and indexbyte2 are used to construct an index into the run-time constant pool of the current class (§2.6), where the value of the index is (indexbyte1 << 8) | indexbyte2.

This means that the instruction `invokevirtual 00 02` will invoke the method whose methodref is at index `(00 << 8) | 02` in the constantpool, i.e., at position 2. Remember that the first entry in the constantpool has index 1, so index 2 actually refers to the second entry of the pool.